# Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth' and No such module 'FirebaseAuth' errors

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

With just "import Firebase", when trying to use Auth.auth(), I get an "unresolved identifier "Auth" error. When I try adding the "Import FirebaseAuth", I get a "No such module "FirebaseAuth" error.

My Podfile includes "Firebase/Core", "Firebase/Auth", and "Firebase/Database". I've tried adding every import and pod that people have recommended.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
//import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pin: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonRegister(sender: UIButton) {
        let loginName = name.text
        let loginPin = pin.text

        Auth.auth().createUser(name: name!, pin: pin!, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //reg success
            } else {
                //reg fail
            }
        })
    }//end button reg
```

My Podfile is currently:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'dyeStats' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for dyeStats
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'


end
```

Comment: Do not _describe_ what you've tried. _Show_ us. We have no reason to believe that your podfile is right. Show it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code and podfile look correct, although you should bump the iOS version to 13.0.  I believe though, you're using an older version of swift and/or Firebase. The Auth.auth() line completion used to have `FIRUser` but now has a `FIRAuthDataResultCallback` which returns a `AuthDataResult `. See the [6.2 Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios). As a test, I would suggest downloading the [cocoapods.app](https://cocoapods.org/app), remove the pods from the app and then reinstall. Also, what call is this createUser with a pin?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you opened `dyeStats.xcworkspace` instead of `dyeStats.xcodeproj` which is generated by pod. Don't forget to import `FirebaseAuth` header file.

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: dyeStats.xcworkspace is what is being opened, FirebaseAuth is what I am trying to import that is giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pod install command as it could be that you did not install those. Also provide your podfile so that we can make sure that it is formatted correctly.